# problem with adding data from DB to jtable

Tags: java, database, jtable

i want to add all my data from DB to jtable, but using this code i get only the last row from DB, added to the table severelal times.
Can someone tell where is mistake?

```
public Vector getOrder() throws Exception
{ 
    DbConnection();
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet res =null;
    String query="Select * From Orders;";

try{
    st=connect.createStatement();
    res=st.executeQuery(query);
    Vector v =new Vector();
    Vector<String> record = new Vector<String>();
    int i=0;
    while(res.next())
    { 
    record.clear();
        uzsakNr=res.getString("Uzsakymo_nr");           
        priemDat=res.getString("Priemimo_data");
        irengPav=res.getString("Irenginio_pavadinimas");
        model=res.getString("Modelis");
        status=res.getString("Statusas");
        grazDat=res.getString("Grazinimo_data");
        clientId=Long.toString(res.getLong("ClientId"));

        //record.addElement(i);
        record.addElement(uzsakNr);
        record.addElement(priemDat);
        record.addElement(irengPav);
        record.addElement(model);
        record.addElement(status);
        record.addElement(grazDat);
        record.addElement(clientId);
        //record.addElement("");
        v.addElement(record);       
        i++;
    }
    //Zle vydaji, daji tyko trzy takiesame ostatnie
    System.out.println(v);
    return v;
}finally {
    if(res!=null) res.close();
    if(st!=null) st.close();
}

}
```

in another class

```
        try{
        Vector ve=db.getOrder();

        String heading[]={"uzsakNr","priemDat","irengPav","model","status","grazDat","ClientID"};
        Vector columnHeads= new Vector();
        for (int i=0;i<heading.length; i++)
            columnHeads.addElement(heading[i]);

        table = new JTable(ve,columnHeads);
        table.addMouseListener(new TableMouseListener());
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        UzsakPanel.add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 10, 901, 200);
        }catch(Exception e2){e2.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,

Replace the line containing `clear()`  with `Vector<String> record = new Vector<String>();`

Secondly, I think what you're doing is probably correct but your printing is the problem.

Since you have a vector of vectors containing strings, I would print it like so

```
for(Vector stringVect : v) {
    for(String s : stringVect) {
        System.out.print(s+ '\t');
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: to be correct i get vector containng for example thee element that are made off all thee rows from dtb

Comment: @Edgar  think you had a problem with printing the vector. See my refactored answer.

Comment: +1, forgetting to create a new row Vector for each row in the ResultSet is the common mistake.